# Attach to all possible relations from many-to-many method on create?

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, database-relations

I have two Model named Position and Event, they have many-to-many relationship with each other.

- Event:

```
<?php

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'opta_id'
    ];

    public function positions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Position::class);
    }
}
```

- Position:

```
class Position extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'short_name'
    ];

    public function events() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
    }
}
```

Each `event` should have a pivot entry for each `position` currently in the database, there are no exceptions. So every time a user creates a new `event`, I want to create a pivot entry for each existing `position`.

I am struggling to figure this out using the documentation and SO. I could use sync() or attach() to make the connections by explicitly naming the IDs of all the positions in the db. In the `EventController`'s `store` method:

```
$data = $request->all();
$event = Event::create($data);
$event->positions()->sync([1, 22, 34, 167]);
```

But for this to work, I would first have to get all the entries from the `positions` table, format them into an array of IDs, and pass them to this method. Is there any built-in or canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in way, but the manual solution is quite short:

```php
$event->positions()->attach(Position::pluck('id'));
```

`attach()` is more efficient than `sync()` because it inserts all pivot records in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the other solution, So to may achieve your purpose you have

```
// the 1st sync will remove all the relationship to the position table
$event->positions()->sync([1, 22, 34, 167]);
// the 2nd sync is to extend the relationship from the 1st
$event->positions()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 22, 34, 167]);
```